# How can I input a string of comma separated numbers, and then reverses its order and displays the reversed array in C#

Tags: php

I am supposed to use the built-in explode and implode functions in my code.
For example, 
if the input is 12, 56, 34, 79, 26 
the output should be reverse is 26  79  34  56  12.

and here is my code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrbyB.png)

Answer (score 0):

first, assuming input as string, use

```
String myInput = "12, 56, 34, 79, 26";    
string[] inputs = str.Split(',');
Array.Reverse(inputs);
```

else if you want to derive your own method, see this great stack over flow anser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088287/reverse-an-array-without-using-array-reverse)