# Reverse Array A-Z C#

Tags: c#

How do you reverse the list in order to display A-Z in reverse from "ZYX....A" I tried to create the ReverseAlpha method but I'm not sure what to do from there.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    //variable declarations
    const int SIZE = 26;
    char[]
    alpha = new char[SIZE];
    //function calls
    FillAlpha(alpha);
    Console.WriteLine("Print Original List A-Z:");
    PrintAlpha(alpha);
    ReverseAlpha(alpha);
    Console.WriteLine("\nPrint Reversed List Z-A:");
    PrintAlpha(alpha);
    Console.Write("\n\nPress any key to continue:");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void FillAlpha(char[] letters) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        letters[i] = (char)(i + 65);
    }
}

static void PrintAlpha(char[] letters) {
    foreach(char c in letters)
    Console.Write(c + " ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

static void ReverseAlpha(char[] letters) {
    char a, b, temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp:
}
```

Comment: Imagine you have 10 boxes in a row in front of you. How would you reorder the contents of those boxes so that it was in reverse order after you complete?

Comment: Your `ReverseAlpha` function doesn't do anything. You should try harder.

Comment: More importantly, your `ReverseAlpha` method doesn't even compile.  Make sure your code actually compiles first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse an array without using Array.Reverse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088287/reverse-an-array-without-using-array-reverse)

Comment: It would probably be better to give your methods more meaningful names. You have a variable named `alpha`, which happens to be a char array, but your methods will work on any array so consider leaving `Alpha` out of the method names, and instead do something like `static void FillArray(char[] input, int size)`

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    static char[] ReverseAlpha(char[] letters)
    {
        letters = letters.Reverse().ToArray(); 
        return letters;
    }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You reference array.Reverse(), but your code is using System.Linq

Comment: actually, I was wrong - calling `letters.Reverse();` *does* reverse the original array. Sorry!